Efficient Merge sort implementation in python
def merge(arr, l, m, r):
    merged_arr = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while (i < len(arr[l:m])) and (j < len(arr[m:r+1])):
        if arr[l+i] < arr[m+j]:
            merged_arr.append(arr[l+i])
            i += 1
        elif arr[l+i] >= arr[m+j]:
            merged_arr.append(arr[m+j])
            j += 1
    merged_arr.extend(arr[m+j:r+1])
    merged_arr.extend(arr[l+i:m])
    arr[l:r+1] = merged_arr
    return

def merge_sort(arr, l, r):
    if r > l:
        m = (l + r) // 2
        merge_sort(arr, l, m)
        merge_sort(arr, m+1, r)
        return merge(arr, l, m, r)


I am not sure what is wrong with my merge function. The following works well:
print(merge([1,4,7,8,9,20,  0,4,5,15,67,68], 0, 6,12)) 
However, this does not give correct output:
print(merge_sort([1, 5, 4, 2, 33, 4, 2, 44, 22, 0], 0, 10))

We have an invariant that l < r. What other invariants can you write down, e.g. how do l and m relate? How do m and r relate? Add assert statements to your code, and show us the result.

Trace through it: first find "some short list" that fails, like just [1,5,4] and then step through your code, using print statements if you have to: at what point does what you think should happen, stop happening? Also, on a more general note, you want merge_sort to either just take an array and spit out the result, or have those l and r arguments default to something (like (arr, l=0, r=len(arr))), and add a return statement for when r is not greater than l.

Thanks for your comment. I did that. Somehow if I replace all the occurrences of m with m+1 in merge(...) function then it works. But I am not able to understand why that should matter.

The end index for slicing is not inclusive:
def merge(arr, l, m, r):
    L, R, i, j = arr[l:m], arr[m:r], 0, 0
    merged_arr = []
    while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
        if L[i] < R[j]:
            merged_arr.append(L[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            merged_arr.append(R[j])
            j += 1
    merged_arr.extend(L[i:])
    merged_arr.extend(R[j:])
    arr[l:r] = merged_arr


def merge_sort(arr, l, r):
    if r - l > 1:
        m = (l + r) // 2
        merge_sort(arr, l, m)
        merge_sort(arr, m, r)
        merge(arr, l, m, r)


A = [1, 5, 4, 2, 33, 4, 2, 44, 22, 0]
merge_sort(A, 0, len(A))
print(A)


Prints
[0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 22, 33, 44]

